# Getting changed data from Model - Active Record 5/ Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using Active record 5 in my custom Ruby script.

**(Controller/Rake task)**

```
books.each do |book|
  b_id = book[“b_id”]
  bk = Books.where(book_id: b_id).first
  bk = Books.new(book_id: b_id) unless bk
  bk.update_book_info(book)
  if bk.changed?
    # ...send book title to Api...
    bk.save! 
  end
end
```

**(Model)**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :get_title
  def update_book_info(book)
    @book = book
  end

  private
  def  get_title
    # do ..something
    self.title = @book[’title’]
  end

 end
```

`books` is an array.

Please note the `[...send book title to Api...]` part. I need to know the 
book title so that I can send it to API. I have tried `bk.title`  but it returns `null`!

How to get the book title ?

Also, can I move more code from controller to model?

Help :)

Comment: Can you provide more information about the `books` variable? Is it an `Array` of `Hash`? Or is it already model instances? The solution depends on it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Books is an array.

Comment: I'm assuming the "s" in the `Books` is a type and really exists a column called `book_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If it returns `nil` ... Then it is empty.
Check the object in your rails console.
In your terminal, run:

```
rails c
```

Then:

```
Book.first # see the whole object
Book.first.title # see its title
Book.all.pluck(:title) # see all the titles in the database
```

You might want to check where you save your books if there isn't something wrong which would cause the title not to be saved.

Side note: in your code, you're doing some unnecessary queries. 
In your `each` loop, you're querying the database for an object your already have. 
This line:

```
bk = Books.where(book_id: b_id).first # useless query
```

Is going to return the same `book` object from which you extracted the `id`.
Also, when looking for an object with an id, no need to use `where` since an id is unique, it can only return one object. Use `#find` or `#find_by`.

Comment: Title is not nil!

Answer (score 0):

Instead create the method `#update_book_info` you could use [`#assign_attributes(new_attributes)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) like this:

`bk.assign_attributes(book)`

It will guarantee that your model will be *dirt* and the `#changed?` method will work. Also, your `bk#title` will be loaded before the `#save`, which seems to be what you want.

Then you will be able to remove the `before_save` and `#get_title` as well.